# Multiple regression with binary predictors. Component value analysis

Tags: methodology, multiple-regression

I have the data about process duration (in minutes) and components (procedures) done during it like this (CSV):

---

```
id,time,p1,p2,p3,p4
1,30,1,0,0,0
2,32,1,0,0,0
3,56,1,1,0,0
4,78,1,1,0,1
5,78,1,1,0,1
6,100,1,1,1,1
7,98,0,1,1,1
```

I need to estimate the duration of each component(procedure) 
I want to get something like this:

```
component,timeMax,timeMin,timeAverage,timeSD,samples
p1,...
p2,....
p3,...
p4,....
```

**Note:** I need the estimated time of procedures not time of processes where procedure was used.

I think the solution shold initially group all combinations first and then 
simple procedures (1 process = 1 procedure ) time shuld be evaluated

$$t_1 = 30$$ #id=1
$$t_1 = 32$$ #id=2

then more complex actions should be performed: for example, time of procedure 2 (from sample) could be calculated by subtraction:

$$t_1 = \sum{(t_1+t_2+t_3+t_4)} - \sum{(t_2+t_3+t_4)} = 100 - 98 = 2$$ # id 6 - 7
$$t_2 = \sum{(t_1+t_2)} - t_1 = 56 - 30\pm1 = 26\pm1$$ #id 3 - (1,2)
$$t_3 = \sum{(t_1+t_2+t_3+t_4)} - \sum{(t_1+t_2+t_4)} = 100 - 78 = 22$$ # id 6 - 5
$$t_4 = \sum{(t_1+t_2+t_4)} - \sum{(t_1+t_2)} = 78 - 56 = 22$$ #id 4 - 3

then average, SD, Min,Max for all $t_i$ is calculated.

If there are several procedures are always combined time for each is calculated by dividing combination time by combination size. I think this procedure should be performed only before result output.

May be also some kind of correction for procedures that are performed during this sequence.

May be there should be iteration limit, or stop condition then last iteration brings no or <1% result change in comparison with previous one.

The second part is to compare procedure times when it is done separately and in combination with others. And to estimate most effective (reducing total time) and ineffective (increasing total time) procedure combinations.

The question is:

- How to achieve this?
- What methods should/could be used?
- What statistical software could be used for this task?

Comment: The first step is grouping of simmilar cases and calculating min,max,count,average and SD for all of them.
The second is to make subtraction of this (grouped) records.

Comment: It looks like the desired method should be a **multiple regression** with one continuous dependent variable and multiple independent/predictor **binary** variables. Like logistic regression but vice-versa and multiple predictors.

Comment: Found article about [Multiple Regression with Categorical Variables](http://www.psychstat.missouristate.edu/multibook/mlt08m.html), but this technique requires coding of dummy variables, wich is not suitable in my case (>50 binary predictors and the number may extend in future).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the problem, as is, is well-defined. You mention the possibility that the duration of each operation may vary if done in combination with others. If that's the case, the "duration of operation" is not defined. E.g. in your example, op1 time is 30-32 min, and you say "therefore op2 time is 24-26 min", but how do you know that? Maybe op1, when done together with op2, takes only 10 min and op2 takes the remaining 46 min. So you'd need some more assumptions to figure out individual durations from such data.

If you assume the operations are independent, then it seems that an easy first step would be to build a set of linear equations. In your example, the first three equations would be:

$$t_1 = 30$$
$$t_1 = 32$$
$$t_1 + t_2 = 56$$

Then solve it (in the least squares sense). The way to solve it is probably using linear regression, with operation durations as independent variables and the process times as (known) dependent variables. Standard regression solvers will give you all kinds of estimates of variance.

Solution for R:

```
d <- read.table("data.csv",header=T,sep=",") # read data
r <- lm(time ~ 0+p1+p2+p3+p4, data=d) # multiple linear regression 
summary(r) #result output
```

Comment: Yes, sort of. Was rewriting question while you answered. But I have ~1000 records and ~50 components in real task.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a problem, you can do simple linear regression with many more variables. Even non-linear regression is feasible I think.

Comment: What is the best way to do this. I know how to solve simple quations on paper.. but do not know how to achieve this on computer for the scale I need. Could you tell me there should I search?

Comment: I think almost any decent software for numerical computations can do regression. You can even do it in Excel (also in Matlab, R, probably octave, python, etc.). I'd search for "linear regression in X", where X is your favorite environment. If you don't have a favorite, I'd recommend R, because it's free and powerful. Here's a [link](http://www.jeremymiles.co.uk/regressionbook/extras/appendix2/R/) to a tutorial on doing regressions in R. The specific R command you probably want is glm.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but Statistica 8 complains about type of independent variables while trying to perform multiple linear regression analysis. Is this type of analysis is suitable for boolean (1/0) independent/predictor variables?

Comment: The standard linear regression assumes the independent variables are continuous. It should work without a problem for the specific case when the only values that you observe are 0 and 1. The problem you have with the software might just be a question of casting to a different data type.

Comment: A deeper issue is that a more elaborate model might take into account the binary nature of the variables and do it more efficiently or more accurately. But I don't know of any such standard models. So I'd try the standard regression first and look for alternatives only if that doesn't work.

Comment: It does not work. At least with the raw data. It returns Beta,beta std err, B, B std err, t(2),p last two are about significance, Nor B, nor Beta nor their combination in $y=\beta*x+B$ maner give me the desired results. The most close results I got with "breakdown table" method (Statistica 8) - it calculated initial ranges for all variants.

Comment: I ran regression in Matlab with the set of 7 procedures and four operations in your opening post. The results it gave are: [25 31 34 22] for the operation times, with confidence interval for the first operation time of [4, 47], and similar values for the others. Keep in mind that this is on a very small set. So my question is, do you get similar results and just want something different? E.g. it gives you a (probabilistic) confidence interval and maybe you want hard constraints instead. Or do you get something completely different?

Comment: Looks like I do something wrong. I get completely different results in Statistica. I had tried R for this: 
`d <- read.table("data.csv",header=T,sep=",")
r <- lm(time ~ p1+p2+p3+p4, data=d)
summary(r)
p1             2.000  
p2            25.000 
p3            22.000
p4            22.000 
`
Results are closer, but still strange. I think I did something wrong with lm function.

Comment: It looks like what you did was "regression with offset". I.e. the function implicitly adds a column of all ones and tries to build a linear function with offset. I expect it wouldn't matter on your large dataset, but for a small dataset it skews the result. What you should try is "regression through origin" (i.e. without the offset). I believe the command is time ~ 0+p1+p2+p3+p4.

Comment: Looks like the solution! Thank you very much!!! May I edit your answer to insert the R code?

Comment: Sure. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Software:
I advice to use R because it is free and designed for data analysis.
http://cran.r-project.org/

About your first question, the R code to answer it, is the following (I suppose that your data are in the file "data.csv")

```
# load the file "data.csv"
d <- read.table("data.csv",header=T,sep=",")

# create a data frame for the results
res <- data.frame(component=paste("op",1:(ncol(d)-2),sep=""),timeMax=rep(0,ncol(d)-2),timeMin=rep(0,ncol(d)-2),timeAverage=rep(0,ncol(d)-2),timeSD=rep(0,ncol(d)-2),samples=rep(0,ncol(d)-2))

# loop over the operations
for (ind in 3:ncol(d))
    {
    res[ind-2,2:6]<-c(max(d$time*d[,ind]),min(d$time*d[,ind]),mean(d$time*d[,ind]),sd(d$time*d[,ind]),sum(d[,ind]))
    }
```

For the question about the combinations, you could use the same trick by replacing
`d$time*d[,ind]`
by
`d$time*d[,ind1]*d[,ind2]`
if you want to obtain statistics about the combination of op1 and op2. But if you have many op, this is maybe not suited to your case as the number of combinations is equal to 2^N... Is N large? Do you want statistics about all the possible combinations or only about some of them?

Comment: this returns the time of processes there operation was used not the estimated time of operation. Thank you for trying.

component timeMax timeMin timeAverage   timeSD samples
1       op1     100      30    62.33333 27.98333       6
2       op2     100       0    52.00000 42.61455       4
3       op3     100       0    16.66667 40.82483       1
4       op4     100       0    42.66667 47.42433       3

Comment: How do you define the "time of operation" if it's not the time of the processes where the operation is used? Is it the time of the process divided by the number of operations used in that process or...?

Comment: I had updated question and tried to explain that I mean.