# How to estimate time-per-product in a factory?

Tags: data-visualization, modeling

Workers in a factory are assembling items built from several parts. For each item they fetch the parts from the warehouse and then assemble the items.

I suppose they need a certain time per item for assembly plus a certain time per part for fetching them.

$D_{order} = n_{items} * D_{fetch} + n_{parts} * D_{assemble}$

I have a list of past orders which tells me

- $n_{items}$: how many items there are in that order
- $n_{parts}$: how many parts there are in that order and
- $D_{order}$: how long it took the worker to complete the order.

I want to estimate, based on the number of items and parts, how long a future order will take. So I need to find out $D_{fetch}$ and $D_{assemble}$.

Which is the best way to plot the data to estimate those two factors?

Here is some sample data (order completion time on the Y-axis):

This chart shows the time to complete an order vs. the overall number of parts in it:

[image: time_vs_parts]

This chart shows the time to complete an order vs. the number of assembled items in it:

[image: time_vs_items]

What I didn't tell before: Usually several of the items are the same product, so maybe there is a overhead per product for getting/reading the appropriate blueprints.
So this chart shows the time to complete an order vs. the number of unique products in it:

[image: time_vs_unique_products]

Comment: Is plotting it a requirement? There are pretty good ways of estimating the factors without plotting.

Comment: Not a requirement. Any way is ok.

Comment: This model you've devised:

Dorder=nitems∗Dfetch+nparts∗Dassemble

Are there good reasons to believe that's how it works, or is that just a first stab at it?

How many distinct items are there, relative to the number of orders for which you have the time the total order took?

Comment: That is just a guess. Certainly they are running around fetching parts and certainly they are sitting there assembling items and sometimes they are drinking coffee, but I don't know how all these times contribute to the overall time. I updated the question with some Excel charts of the actual data.

Comment: Did you try simple regression, along the lines of this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7531/multiple-regression-with-binary-predictors-component-value-analysis/7545#7545?

Comment: Reading the text I understand all the three graphs have "time to complete an order" as vertical axis, in other words $D_{order}$. However, the highest data point is at 40, 69 and 36, respectively. Why is this?

Comment: Good point. That is because I just entered some scaling values that gave a nice picture. :/ The highest data point (in all three cases, of course) is actually 182 but that is just an outlier. So there are a few data points outside the visible range.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the amount of time it takes to complete an order, it seems that a duration analysis (aka survival or event history analysis) would be most appropriate. See the Wikipedia entry for an overview:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis

This introduction, which covers issues such as censoring, looks relevant and accessible:

[Survival Analysis Introduction](http://www.amstat.org/chapters/northeasternillinois/pastevents/presentations/summer05_Ibrahim_J.pdf)

And if you are so inclined, R has a task view dedicated to survival analysis:

[R Survival Analysis Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html)

Since you know pretty well what steps go into the production of each item, and because you seem interested in forecasting, you may begin by estimating a parametric model, such as a Weibull or log-logistic/log-normal. Most software capable of estimating these models will also provide the tools to forecast average time-to-completion for different orders. You should also be able to produce plots of estimated durations.